# Executing HTML code inside a DIV through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

*<sub>I have seen many questions like this one, but my question is slightly different.</sub>*

I wrote an HTML code that can execute another HTML code inside a `<div>`. The page looks like this:
[image]

The code of this page is this:

```
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <style>
        html, body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        textarea {width:100%; height: 28%;}
        div {display: block; width: 100%;}
    </style>
    <body onload="loadData()" onbeforeunload="storeData()" onunload="this.onbeforeunload()">
        <div style="overflow: auto;">
            <textarea id="code"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="run()" style="float: left;">Run</button>
            <button onclick="setSize()" style="float: right;">Set size</button>
            <input type="number" id="size" style="float: right; text-align: right;"/>
        </div>
        <div id="result" style="overflow: auto; height: 70%; border-top: 2px solid black;"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        const editor=document.getElementById('code');
        function run()
        {
            var res=document.getElementById('result');
            var input=editor.value;
            res.innerHTML=input;
        }
        function setSize()
        {
            editor.style.fontSize=document.getElementById("size").value;
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].style.fontSize=document.getElementById("size").value;
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].style.fontSize=document.getElementById("size").value;
            document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.fontSize=document.getElementById("size").value;
        }
        function storeData()
        {
            var data=document.getElementById("code").value;
            var txtSize=document.getElementById("size").value;
            localStorage.setItem("stored", data);
            localStorage.setItem("size", txtSize);
        }
        function loadData()
        {
            var data=localStorage.getItem("stored");
            var txtSize=localStorage.getItem("size");
            document.getElementById("code").value=data;
            document.getElementById("size").value=txtSize;
            editor.style.fontSize=txtSize;
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].style.fontSize=document.getElementById("size").value;
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].style.fontSize=document.getElementById("size").value;
            document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].style.fontSize=document.getElementById("size").value;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

It is working absolutely correct, except one thing. The problem is that, if a `<button>` is created and the `onclick` attribute has this code: `document.write('Some text');`, then the whole page gets cleared. See these screenshots:
[image]

[image]

So, can you tell any way by which I can ensure that no changes can be done to the original page?
Please help a class 10 student.

Comment: Calling `document.write()` after the initial page load *always* obliterates the page. Use other DOM APIs to update page content.

Comment: I'd try wrapping the result in an iframe, and perhaps do some code preprocessing (perhaps prepending a line document = iframeId.document;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having 'result' as a regular div element, which is meant to represent a section of the actual page, what you want here is to embed a whole separate page/context, which is something that [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) is used for.

I managed to accomplish what you wanted by replacing the div with an iframe, and the first line in the 'run' method with this:

```
var res=document.getElementById('result').contentDocument.body;
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eimamovic1/2sty5uxf/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my _scattered explanation_ and for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I have a small suggestion for your future questions - make it as copy-pasteable as possible (for example, I had to type the button element by myself - not a big effort, I know, but something we all prefer to avoid). Another suggestion is to make use of code playgrounds like JsFiddle, Codepen, etc. instead of making screenshots - it would be both faster for you to make a question and for us to see what's exactly going on. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will definitely try those.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that, if a  is created and the onclick attribute has this code: `document.write('Some text');`, then the whole page gets cleared.

That is exactly what is supposed to happen when `document.write()` is called. That function always replaces the entire page with whatever is in the quotes.

The solution is to simply never call that method. If there is some reason why you want to call `document.write`, you need to explain what that is in your question so we can suggest an appropriate alternative.

Comment: I don't want to call that method. But the one who will use this page, may invoke it. So, my question is, how to protect the entire page from getting cleared by user input. **Anyway, I have already got a perfect answer.**